# How to create extendible xml

Tags: xml

How do I create an xml schema such that in the future when there is a need to enter a completely new object, the schema does not need to be edited? I studied through w3schools and other sites -- but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to [XML namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#scoping), which allow you to use prefixes to incorporate tags from different schemas.

The example from the linked page:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- both namespace prefixes are available throughout -->
<bk:book xmlns:bk='urn:loc.gov:books'
         xmlns:isbn='urn:ISBN:0-395-36341-6'>
    <bk:title>Cheaper by the Dozen</bk:title>
    <isbn:number>1568491379</isbn:number>
</bk:book>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will look into it and let you know.